# SQL merge two tables - get only one row for each key value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to run an SQL command on my database. I have two tables, one for users, another one for posts. I want to find last post of each user. I tried following:

```
SELECT b.`username`, b.`id`, c.`home`, c.`text` FROM `sunlight-users` AS b 
LEFT JOIN `sunlight-posts` AS c ON b.`id` = c.`author`
WHERE b.`group` = 1 OR b.`group`=3 OR b.`group`= 5 OR b.`group` = 10 OR b.`group` = 14 OR b.`group` = 
23 OR b.`group` = 25
ORDER by c.`time` DESC
GROUP BY b.`username`
```

It fails with error "your syntax is weird near  GROUP BY b.`username` on line 5".
I tried to run the command with while loop (on the webpage) like this:

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT * FROM `"._mysql_prefix."-users` WHERE `group` = 1 OR `group` = 3 OR `group` = 5 OR `group` = 10 OR `group` = 14 OR `group` = 23 OR `group` = 25");

    while($item = DB::row($query)) {
        $post = DB::query("SELECT type,home,xhome,author,time FROM `"._mysql_prefix."-posts` WHERE ".$knihy." AND `author` = ".item['id']." ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1");
        switch($post['home']){
            case 2:
           //code
                break;

            case 3:
             //code
            break;

            default:
             //code
        }
```

But it looks like the second query is completely ignored, I get default values even though manually typing the query into database gets 2 or 3. I know that running like 50 queries in a loop probably isn't a good idea, that's why I'm trying to do it all at once.
This code:

```
SELECT b.`username`, b.`id`, c.`home`, c.`text` FROM `sunlight-users` AS b 
    LEFT JOIN `sunlight-posts` AS c ON b.`id` = c.`author`
    WHERE b.`group` = 1 OR b.`group`=3 OR b.`group`= 5 OR b.`group` = 10 OR b.`group` = 14 OR b.`group` = 
    23 OR b.`group` = 25
    ORDER by c.`time` DESC
```

results in

```
+----+----------+------+------+
| id | username | home | text |
+----+----------+------+------+
|  1 | user1    |    2 | .... |
|  1 | user1    |    3 | aaaa |
|  0 | user0    |    4 | .... |
+----+----------+------+------+
```

The order is correct, I want just the upper row for each user. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You should also learn NOT to use keywords, such as `group` and `time`, as column names.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not something I have power of (we are using CMS with default tables and quite complex system).

Comment: The different parts of an SQL query must go in a certain order. SELECT first, then WHERE to filter the rows, then GROUP BY to group what's left and last of all is the ORDER BY. 
Also, if you use GROUP BY then you can't SELECT for display the columns not in the grouping since there could be multiple rows meaning multiple different values. You can use functions on these columns to display things like the max or min value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to filter, not group. You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    u.username, 
    u.id, 
    p.home, 
    p.text 
from sunlight_users u
left join sunlight_posts p
    on  u.id = p.author
    and p.time = (select max(p1.time) from sunlight_posts p1 where p1.author = u.id)
where u.group in (1, 3, 5, 10, 14, 23, 25)
order by u.username
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        u.username, 
        u.id, 
        p.home, 
        p.text,
        row_number() over(partition by u.id order by p.time desc) rn
    from sunlight_users u
    left join sunlight_posts p on  u.id = p.author
    where u.group in (1, 3, 5, 10, 14, 23, 25)
) t
where rn = 1
order by u.username
```

Comment: If a user has two posts with the same time then I suppose this query could return both. It should be unlikely but it's worth being aware of this limitation.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that worked! :) EDIT: It's impossible to post at the very same time twice on our webpage, the system will deny your request if you try to do so, so this solution works fine for me :)